# How to find a character in a string using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have getting passed from another funtion, foldername like `foldername  = "a\\b\\c"` or `foldername = "a"` and i'm trying to find the folder name contains `"\\"` and substitute `"\\"` with `"__"`, split foldername based on `"__"` and pass into an array.

please have a look at what i was trying till now.

sample values:

```
If WorksheetFunction.Find("\\", foldername) = 1 Then
       foldername  = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(foldername, "\\", "__")
       SheetNames() = Split(foldername, "__")
End If
```

i'm getting the below error.

[image]

Comment: `INSTR` is the way to check a string in a string.  But can understand what you are trying to achieve?  You can use `REPLACE` in VBA or `foldername = Join(Split(foldername, "\\"), "__")`

Comment: Use [INSTR()](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php)

Comment: INSTR (foldername,"\\") this will return me a number, so are you suggesting change the if condition accordingly?

Comment: With that last edit, your question has joined the **Unclear what you are asking** category.

Comment: use Join by the original and the put back with the __

Comment: Hope the last edit makes the question little more sensible.

Comment: instr works perfectly. I'll post the code please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim a as Integer

'consider current value of is `foldername  = "a\\b\\c"`

a = InStr(foldername, "\\")

'if InStr is not able to find the value funtion returns 0

If a <> 0  Then
       foldername  = Replace(foldername, "\\", "__")
       SheetNames() = Split(foldername, "__")
End If
```

Thanks for your suggestions guys, appreciate it.

Comment: I would strongly recommend not using WorksheetFunction, especially since VBA has a built-in function meant for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
SheetNames() = Split(foldername, "\\")
foldername=join(sheetnames,"__")
```

This will do it.

Comment: Why would you use this approach instead of using the builtin function? Replace(foldername, "\\", "__") would be far more efficient.

Comment: Just an alternative.